# Incorrect rendering of the updated output in rHandsontable object (hot_to_r)

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have found an issue concerning the updated data output.
The script is as follwos:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyapps)
library(rhandsontable)

## CLIENT SIDE
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Test of rHandsontable output - hot_to_r function"),
sidebarPanel(
actionButton("goButton", "test rhandsontable")

),
mainPanel(
  rHandsontableOutput("all_updates")
  ,verbatimTextOutput('df_output')
 )
```

))

```
## SERVER SIDE
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$goButton,{
df <- data.frame ( x=1:10
                 ,y=1:10
                 ,z=factor(c("X","P"))
                 ,merge_xy="merger"
                )
df[,4] <- paste(df[,1],"+",df[,2])
output$all_updates <- renderRHandsontable({

rhandsontable(df, selectCallback = TRUE, height = 300) %>%
hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
hot_rows(rowHeights = 18)
})

})

observeEvent(input$all_updates,{

zzz <- hot_to_r(input$all_updates)
zzz[,4] <- paste(zzz[,1],'+',zzz[,2],'+',zzz[,3]) 
#the output of the modified dataframe
print(zzz)

output$all_updates <-renderRHandsontable({

  rhandsontable(zzz, selectCallback = TRUE, height = 300) %>%
    hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
    hot_rows(rowHeights = 18)

})

print(hot_to_r(input$all_updates))

output$df_output <- renderPrint(
print(hot_to_r(input$all_updates))
)

})

output$all_updates <- renderRHandsontable({
df <- data.frame ( x=integer(10)
                 ,y=integer(10)
                 ,z=factor(c("X","P"))
               ,merge_xy="merger"
                )

rhandsontable(df, selectCallback = TRUE, height = 300) %>%
hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE) %>%
hot_rows(rowHeights = 18)
})
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The issue is that the function 'hot_to_r' return dataset from rHandsontable with one-step delay.

You can experiment with changes to the column Z:

after any changes in the column the output of the table has been updated immediately but the output of 'hot_to_r' function generates the snapshot of the previous version of the table (without latest changes).

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed by the package creator (see  [closed issues](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/91)).